# Implementation of Glide in Recyclerview Adapter crash app,

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

Trying to Implement Glide inside recyclerView App is crashing.
Logcat saying

```
        W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
V/studio.deploy: Package broadcast exit hook { cmd=3, time=75125210000000, thread=2 }
    Fixing application and activity contexts
W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tc, PID: 26232
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null View
        at com.bumptech.glide.GenericRequestBuilder.into(GenericRequestBuilder.java:685)
        at com.bumptech.glide.DrawableRequestBuilder.into(DrawableRequestBuilder.java:457)
        at com.example.tc.TCAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TCAdapter.java:44)
        at com.example.tc.TCAdapter.onBindViewHolder(TCAdapter.java:22)
```

My Implementation code is

```
Glide.with( context ).load( tcImages.get( position ).getFullName() ).into( holder.imageView );
```

My full Adapter code is

```
public class TCAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TCAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    List<TCImages> tcImages;
    Context context;


    ImageView imageView;

    public TCAdapter(List<TCImages> tcImages, Context context){
        this.tcImages = tcImages;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
        View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.item_tc_recycler, parent, false );
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText( tcImages.get( position ).getEmail() );
        Glide.with( context ).load( tcImages.get( position ).getFullName() ).into( holder.imageView );
//        Glide.with( context ).load( "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" ).into( holder.imageView );
//        Toast.makeText(context, tcImages.get( position ).getFullName().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tcImages.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super( itemView );
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.txtItem );
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.imageView );
        }
    }
}
```

Tried pasting direct string of image address even then it's crashing

Comment: add logcat trace please

Comment: @MahmoudAbuElheja Added

Comment: getFullName() is giving url of image

Comment: These answers miss the point, because `ImageView imageView` should obviously be a field in the view-holder (per item) and not a field in the adapter.

Comment: @MartinZeitler he declared it but not used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dependent on your **Logcat** your are load image into **NULL ImageView** from ViewHolder plaese make sure is **Id** of **ImageView** is Correct inside **R.layout.item_tc_recycler** 
when bind imageView here

```
    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.imageView );
```

Comment: Image ID was wrong in layout... Yaaa silly mistake...

Answer (score 2):

There might be something wrong with your image view, it looks like `imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.imageView )` might be null, please check if the id is right and if the view is not null